# Can certificates verify dumped https traffic?

Tags: https, ssl-certificate

Let's suppose, for example, I made a HTTP request to https://example.com and dumped following data

- all certificates up to root CA that used to verify the server when the connection was made
- all raw TCP traffic in both direction
- all unencerypted/decrypted HTTP traffic in both direction
- (optional) additional data generated by client

Then I want to prove that I did make such connection to https://example.com trusted by those CAs and the traffic is not fake or modified on client side, with assumption that the website is "trusted", e.g. it's securely configured and not hacked.

Is this possible?

If possible, what additional data is required to be dumped by the client and how to perform the verification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With enough "additional data generated by client", yes, but the practical answer is "no".

The ciphersuites in use in modern TLS all use a feature known as "[Perfect Forward Secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy)".  The gist is that in addition to the stable asymmetric keypair used for server (and, optionally, client) identity, both the client and the server generate a random Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman (or classic Diffie-Hellman) keypair, do the (EC)DH key negotiation for the session master key, and then both sides promptly forget the temporary private key from that negotiation.  Without either of those (EC)DH private keys you can't re-derive the integrity keys, so you can't prove the session.

Of course, if you *could* re-derive the integrity keys, then you could just forge the session afterwards.  So I guess that, ultimately, either way the answer is "no".